# whats going wrong with my program?

Tags: c

the program is supposed to compare the strings and place them in alphabetical order, but the final printf statement prints garbage...where am i going wrong here?
i have used an array of pointers to strings and declared them in the begining, i have even tried using temp as an array rather than pointer stil doesnt quite work

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    int main()
    {
    int j;
    int i;
        char *temp;
        char *string[5] = {"ibrahim","laura","peter","degea"};
        for ( i = 0; i< 4;i++)
        printf("%s\n", string[i]);  //allocating memory
        for( i = 0; i< 10 ;i++)
        string[i] = (char*)malloc (30 * sizeof(char));               
        temp = (char*)malloc(30*sizeof(char));               
        for ( i=0; i< 3; i++)
        for(j =i+1; j<4; j++)
        {
           if(strcmp(string[i], string[j]) > 0)
           {
             strcpy(temp, string[i]);
             strcpy(string[i], string[j]);
             strcpy(string[j], temp);

           }
        }
        for (i = 0; i< 4; i++)
        {
            printf("%s\n",string[i]);
            puts("\n");
        }
        free(string);
        free(temp);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `string[i] = (char*)malloc (30 * sizeof(char));` what?

Comment: Sorry discard my answer I have deleted..

Comment: @OP, please __DO NOT__ edit your original post based on the answers provided. It makes all the people who bothered to answer look wrong and foolish.

Comment: More precisely, if you do feel the urge to modify your code as you go, preserve the original versions so that questions that address the original versions can be seen to be valid as of the time they were written.  Answering a squirming question is as hard as changing a squirming baby's diaper — and the results can be nearly as messy!

Answer (score 1):

`string[i] = (char*)malloc (30 * sizeof(char));`

This is overwriting the existing initialized values.

## EDIT

```
for( i = 0; i< 10 ;i++)

temp = (char*)malloc(30*sizeof(char));
```

WHAT? you are allocating memory over and over 10 times on a single pointer?

## EDIT 2:

The original post is lost (read Edited). By the time you are reading this answer, both Mr. Jonathan Leffler and this poster migh look like absolute fools in this world.

Comment: The code is a mess because two people have been editing it...it is crazy!

Comment: It was an attempt to improve the layout; unfortunately, it over-wrote the changes by the OP.  That complicates life for everyone.

Answer (score 1):

The code originally destroyed its data array (by allocating new pointers).  Now it seems to throw memory away by allocating `temp` four times (but Jeevan's edit reinstates the old code in indented form).  The old code allocated space for strings but never initialized them (having thrown away the value that was in the array beforehand).

**NB:** any commentary on the code could easily be invalid by the time you're reading the commentary — the code in the question could have changed.

---

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    string[i] = malloc(30);
```

This code tramples out of the bounds of the `string` array (dimension is 5).  It also loses the data originally in the array.

---

You need to use `strcmp()` to compare the strings, but you simply need to swap pointers rather than using `strcpy()` at all.

The comment `// allocating memory` beside a `printf()` statement is misleading, too.

---

This stands a chance of working.  Note that there is no memory allocation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    int j;
    int i;
    char *string[] = { "ibrahim", "laura", "peter", "degea" };

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        printf("%s\n", string[i]);

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (j = i+1; j < 4; j++)
        {
            if (strcmp(string[i], string[j]) > 0)
            {
                char *temp = string[i];
                string[i] = string[j];
                string[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        printf("%s\n",string[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
ibrahim
laura
peter
degea
degea
ibrahim
laura
peter
```

Comment: don't try sorting thousands of strings using this sort algorithm.

Comment: I think better let them finish the editing first. Then we might think of looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the existing string array contents with malloc, that too 10 times.
Please use braces in your code for better understanding

```
  for( i = 0; i< 10 ;i++)
    string[i] = (char*)malloc (30 * sizeof(char));               
    temp = (char*)malloc(30*sizeof(char));
```

can be written as

```
  for( i = 0; i< 10 ;i++) // why to allocate memory ten times, that too overwriting
  {
    string[i] = (char*)malloc (30 * sizeof(char));               
  }

  temp = (char*)malloc(30*sizeof(char));
```

Answer (score 0):

when you declare : 
char *string[5] = {
"ibrahim",
"laura",
"peter",
"degea" };

the pointer *string[0] to *string[3] allocated to a address in the memory, where will stored the init values "ibrahim","laura"...

when you use malloc function for the pointer string[i] = (char*)malloc (30 * sizeof(char));
the pointer *string[0] to *string[4] will be allocated to **another address** in the memory. so the value at these address are different from that you initialized (ibrahim,laura).

you should use static array instead dynamic as below

char temp;

char string[5] = {
"ibrahim",
"laura",
"peter",
"degea" };

remove all the malloc, free function.